# firebase database read in batch - limit read of nested data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this firebase database structure of `topics` * `tasks`. For each topic there are the same tasks with different records (tsX = some timestamp).

```
"topic1": {
  "task1": {
    "ts123": "record data",
    "ts212": "record data",
    ...
  },
  "task2": {
    "ts154": "record data",
    "ts223": "record data",
    ...
  },
"topic2": {...},
...
```

**How can I retrieve for each combination of topic and task only at most X records ordered by timestamp? Expected result is the same tree but with limited number of leaves (records).**

Amount of `topics` * `tasks` could be around 100 * 50, so I'd like to avoid performing `#topics * #tasks` read operations. Is there any way to do that in one/batch read?

(I'm using fb db client for web)

THX!

Comment: Do you use the old database to firestore?

Comment: realtime dababase, so not firestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could denormalize your data and add to your existing database structure another node which will facilitate your query:

```
"topics": {
  "topic1": {
    "task1": {
      "ts123": "record data",
      "ts212": "record data",
      ...
    },
    "task2": {
      "ts154": "record data",
      "ts223": "record data",
      ...
    },
  "topic2": {...},
  ...
},
"topicsTasks": { // <- new first level node
  "topic1_task1": {
     "ts123": "record data",
     "ts212": "record data",
      ...
  },
  "topic1_task2": {
     "ts123": "record data",
     "ts212": "record data",
      ...
  },
  "topic2_task1": {
     "ts123": "record data",
     "ts512": "record data",
      ...
  },
  "topic2_task2": {
     "ts183": "record data",
     "ts282": "record data",
      ...
  },
  ....
```

It is quite classic in NoSQL database modeling to duplicate data in such a way it facilitates/optimises your queries.

---

In order to write simultaneously to the two nodes ("topics" and "topicsTasks"), you would use the `update()` method, as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

---

In order to query the most recent 10 items you would do as follows:

```
database.ref('topicsTasks/topic1_task1').limitToLast(10).once("value")
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.val());
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

Note that `database.ref('topicsTasks/topic1_task1').limitToLast(10)` is a Query. Doc about Query is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Comment: I need to read at most X records for each combination of topic and task, is it possible with your proposed structure?

Comment: Ok, I understand better. Why not having a node "topicX_taskY" and then orderBy() timestamp. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok that's moving the problem one level higher, but the problem with reading in one round X records of each combination remains? Or how do I actually perform the read in one round in such structure to limit num of records for each key: "topicX_taskY"?

Provided link to docs will help me with batch updates, thanks. 

Maybe I could store and override (if there are more) only X number of records (leave newest) for each combination of topic and task, maybe you can show me example of that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no API that will limit the total number of tasks across topics.

If that is a use-case you want to implement, consider adding a data structure to your JSON that allows it, e.g. having a list of all tasks with their topic and update timestamp as a property. Something like:

```
"lastTaskUpdates": {
  "task1": { "lastUpdate": "ts123": topic: "topic1" },
  "task2": { "lastUpdate": "ts154": topic: "topic2" },
  ...
},
```

Now you can easily look up the last update for a specific task at `/lastTaskUpdates/taskId` and query for the most recently updated tasks with:

```
db.child("lastTaskUpdates").orderByChild("lastUpdate").limitToLast(10)
```